# Compile Pygame 1.9.1 from source on Mac OSX 10.9 for Python 3.3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pygame, osx-mavericks

I'd like to start by saying that asking a question here isn't something I do lightly. I've now been attempting to install Pygame 1.9.1 from source for four hours, and I've run into several problems but was able to overcome each one. This is the first one I'm completely stumped on.

After I unpack pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz and cd to the folder, I run 'python3 setup.py install'

```
/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_syswm.h:58:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

After some online research, I read that X11 is no longer included with OSX 10.9, so I installed XQuartz in the hope that it could serve as a replacement.

Xquartz does include 'Xlib.h', but it's filepath is /opt/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h, and the setup script doesn't find it here. I've tried several ways to fix this.

The error process specifically comes up in the build part of the install. I've tried using

```
python3 setup.py config --include-dirs /opt/X11/include
```

as well as

```
python3 setup.py config --include-dirs /opt/X11/include/X11
```

but get the same error.

I read online that installing the Xcode command line tools could fix this problem. I'm ~95% sure I had the command line tools before, but I tried to get them again anyway with 'xcode-select --install' only to be told that 'Can't install the software because it is currently unavailable from the Software Update server'. "No problem," I tell myself and just download the package from the Mac developers site. It doesn't help anything.

I've also tried symlinking with the command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/X11 /opt/X11/include/X11
```

Of everything I've tried, I understand this the least, do I could very well be doing the symlink command wrong.

Two other commands I tried are

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/X11/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/X11/include
```

Just looking at the documentation, I came across a debug option for the startup script.
The output of 'python3 setup.py build -g' is

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygame.display' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -g -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -c src/display.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/src/display.o
In file included from src/display.c:30:
/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_syswm.h:58:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not sure what else I can do, but I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll take a stab.. (ymmv it's a guess)

export INCLUDE=$INCLUDE:/opt/X11/include/X11

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but no luck after this command. (Same error)

Answer (score 1):

`setup.py build|install` commands accepts `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` compiler options, as far as I know.

Thus here, you can do

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include python3 setup.py install
```

You probably need the LDFLAGS as well; I'm not sure about the exact location, but something like

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/X11/lib python3 setup.py install
```

seems logical.

After that, you may have to set your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your `X11` libraries. In case your installation proceeds but your PyGame script won't run and complains about not finding `X11` libraries. Thus

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/X11/lib
```

As for the symbolic link you tried to create: it's the wrong way 'round: the two paths should have been switched, so I guess you got an error because `/opt/X11/include/X11` already exists. But with the above, no symlink is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error when trying to install pygame into my PyCharm project's `virtualenv`. I solved it by `cd`ing to the SDL Framework directory where the error originated and copying the X11 header files into it:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
$ cp -R /opt/X11/include/X11 ./
```

then `$ pip install pygame` ran without errors.